# How do I un-install / remove a click package

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I have installed some click packages on my Ubuntu Touch device. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to be hooked up in the UI soon.  For now:

```
sudo click unregister --user=phablet PACKAGE-NAME
```

... where PACKAGE-NAME is the name displayed in the first column of "click list".

Answer (score 9):

Now if you long-press on an installed app in the Dash it will bring up the Preview, showing a button to Uninstall which works as expected