# Ubuntu Phone: How to uninstall preinstalled apps (bcc sport, bbc, cnet, engadget,...)

Tags: aquaris

Currently, my Ubuntu Phone Aquaris E4.5, wants me to update a bunch of preinstalled apps like engadget, cnet, bbc, euronews, bbc sport.

How can i uninstall those apps?

Comment: Does this apply? http://askubuntu.com/questions/347879/how-do-i-un-install-remove-a-click-package

Answer (score 2):

Go to Ubuntu store, search for app and then select Uninstall.
I just got mine today and will search for another solution and believe this can also be done via Terminal mode

Comment: Thanks - this worked like a charm. btw: searching for 'scope' in the ubuntu store lists other maybe useful or already installed scopes

Answer (score 1):

BBC, Euronwes, 7digital, etc. aren't Apps, but Scopes.
It's a known problem.
Actually in Triaged --> https://bugs.launchpad.net/today-scope/+bug/1446535