# Uninstall default scopes in a ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

I am using an ubuntu phone (version OTA-9.1). I want to delete extra scopes. When I search them in the `Ubuntu Store` with the keyword `scope`, i cannot reach more than 100 entries. This means that I cannot delete scope like `youtube scope` without searching them one by one.

Do you have any solution to uninstall these scopes without searching them one by one?

**Edit**

As it is written here http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/there-is-a-sentence-in-this-ubuntu-phone-interview-that-worries-me-a-bit/2071/5 the  *Yahoo Finance* is installed by BQ and it seems there is no way to remove it. Does someone got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the apps-scope and tap for a loong time to that app you would like to uninstall. The Phone will switch automatically to the app-Store showing the corresponding app.

Comment: I do understand that but the defaults scopes provided by Canonical do not appear in this list. To delete them, I have to look them one by one. (For instance I do not need *Yahoo Finance* scope in my BQ aquaris ...)

Answer (score 0):

Some (but not all) scopes can be unregistered using the terminal app or another way to get a terminal on the phone and the `click` application. See [How do I un-install / remove a click package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347879/how-do-i-un-install-remove-a-click-package) for more information, and take a look at the other options to use `click` and use `$ click list` to determine the name of installed packages.

---

I know that this isn't necessarily a full removal for some scopes / apps, as they might persist as unused files, but it is the next thing I know.

This does not work for all scopes (e.g. apps not managed by click don't appear), but that way I could remove / unregister certain scopes I did not find in the `Ubuntu Store`.

However, I still have the *Yahoo Finance* scope you mention in the comment installed, not knowing how to remove it.